# Installing .Net framework 4.5 or 4.6 to MS visual studio community 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, installation, frameworks

I installed MS visual studio community 2017 along with all the necessary plugins but when I am trying to create a web application in C# only the .net frameworks upto 3.5 are available and as a result I can not create MVC based C# web applications because only the option empty web application appears. I installed the .net framework 4.6.2 development pack separately but even that the issue could not be corrected. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: To confirm the installed .NET Framework versions on your computer, please check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and which workload did you installed? You can re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and right click the icon beside 'Modify', 'Launch', choose 'Repair' to repair it.

Comment: I did all of them yet only the .net framewors upto 3.5 only appears

Comment: What’s your OS version? Do you mean the .NET Framework 4.6 or other versions already installed your computer, but the VS 2017 only display the .NET Framework 3.5, right?  I need your help to collect the installation logs. You can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder and upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/, share the link here.

Comment: Amal, have you tried the Bradley solution in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45024508/588023