# Why is Dot Net Framework 4.5.2 not available in my Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I recently upgraded to VS2017 and uninstalled VS2015.
However when I open my old projects in VS2015 Framework 4.5.2 does not show as an option.

[image: Target Framework Combo]

When I attempted to install Framework 4.5.2 I receive the following message

[image]

with link to [Microsoft support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations)  which states that no action is necessary.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate N service Pack 1

[Update]

After trying to remove and restore framework 4.5.2 I tried to repair.
The repair attempt ended with the message

```
Setup operation failed
```

Here is the log

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)

Incomplete components
    Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist,version=4.6.81.6' failed to repair.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist;PackageAction=Repair;ReturnCode=5100
    Impacted workloads
        Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Impacted components
        Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\kirstenAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170711130222_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist,version=4.6.81.6\dotNetFx-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /repair /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage Visual_Studio_15_Setup /CEIPconsent /log "C:\Users\kirstenAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170711130222_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log"
        Return code: 5100
        Return code details: Asia
```

I don't know if it is relevant but I did use the following installer some time ago to get rid of VS2015 I think
[from this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases)

I just noticed that VS2015 was showing in Programs and Features, so I tried un-installing VS2015.  I came up with [this message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/secondary-installer-third-party-app) However I don't think I ever installed the "Secondary Installer"

Answer (score 3):

Go in to the "Visual Studio 2017 Installer" (it should be a shortcut in your Start Menu) and click "Modify". At the top, select "Individual Components".  Make sure that the ".NET Framework 4.5.2 targeting pack" is checked.  If it isn't, select it, and click "Modify" at the bottom right.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it is checked. I am  going to try un-checking it then modifying then re-checking it

Comment: Maybe try unselecting it and letting it uninstall, then going back in re-adding it.

Comment: There is also a "Repair" option on the first screen of the installer (under the 3 lines to the right of Launch).  I'd give that a shot if removing and re-adding the targeting pack doesn't work.

Comment: I have "Unknown Error" when I try to launch now, after re-installing 4.5.2  I have started the repair.

Comment: How did the repair go?

Comment: I can't remember whether it solved the "Unknown Error" issue.  I wound up having to do a complete uninstall and reinstall to solve my problem.

Comment: I just ran into this problem, but after a fresh re-install of Windows 10 and all application software, so I don't think this is related to earlier versions.
Since I have lots of .Net 4.0 apps to support I am going to uninstall 2017 and go back to 2013 which I know works.

Comment: By the way, for anyone discovering this thread, Visual Studio 2017 is horribly slow compared to 2013 even after implementing all of Microsoft's performance tuning tips for Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

A complete uninstall of VS2015 and VS2017 and then a reinstall of VS2017 only fixed the issue.

I had thought I had previously un-intalled VS2015 but an uninstaller remained in Programs and Features so I used it.